# OS X Installer limit a Package to OS version range

Tags: macos, installation

I have spent two days analyzing my options without coming up with a satisfying answer to this problem: what is the best and easiest way to set up an Installer that installs two different versions of of a package based on OS version range such as 10.6 - 10.8 and >10.8.

Is there an undocumented Key in PackageInfo that could be edited?
If I create a project, is there some code I could use in the Distribution.dist file to control the process of installing one package and not the other.

I really would rather not use a post flight script with ditto to do this, it would be really ugly.

Ideally, the excellent Packages would have an option, but does not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the generous help from Stephane.
Using his excellent Packages IDE, it turns out that you can configure a range of options in the Installation Type Presentation pane.
Custom Install and Option can be hidden. It is possible to identify a large range of interdependent options that are linked. You can also create JavaScript, if this is not enough.

His IDE is highly recommended!

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

Comment: Packages can only restrict the minimum OS version to 10.8. Is there other way to restrict to 10.9? Thanks.

Comment: I found new version of packages (1.1.2) support minimum version to 10.10.